# Sphinx substitution in URL

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I have two projects A and B, project A's docs are being hosted for different versions, so the doc urls have the format

```
http://example.org/A/1.0.0/+d/index.html
http://example.org/A/1.0.1/+d/index.html
http://example.org/A/1.2.3/+d/index.html
```

Project B depends on A's of specific version. In B's docs, I want to leave a link to A's docs like this:

"See also [A's documentation](http://example.com/A/1.0.1/+d/index.html) (v 1.0.1)"

Is this possible to pass the version variable to the URL? I tried using `rst_prolog`:

`conf.py`:

```py
rst_prolog = '''
.. |a-ver| replace:: {ver}
'''.format(
    ver=meta.__a_dep_version__,
)
```

`index.rst`:

```
A's version: |a-ver| # this produces the correct output
See also `framework docs <http://example.com/A/|a-ver|/index.html>`_.
```

but getting the URL `https://example.com/A/%7Ca-ver%7C/+d/index.html` after doc building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`sphinx.ext.extlinks`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.6/ext/extlinks.html) extension for this.

### Example

#### Sphinx configuration

```
extlinks = {'docs': ('http://example.org/A/%s/+d/index.html', 'framework docs ')}
```

#### Your documentation

```
:docs:`1.0.1`
.. Result -> framework docs 1.0.1

:docs:`documentation (1.2.3) <1.2.3>`
.. Result -> documentation (1.2.3)
```